# spring batch: How to set up a job repository for every job

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am running multiple jobs and I would like to have a separate job repository (in-memory implementation) for each job.

Please find below the bean definitions that I tried. Please note that I have tried to specify the bean with scope prototype.

I get a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JobExecution must already be saved` exception.

```
<bean id="jobLauncher"
      class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
  <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobRepository"
      class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository" 
      scope="prototype"> 
  <constructor-arg> 
    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobInstanceDao"/> 
  </constructor-arg> 
  <constructor-arg> 
    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobExecutionDao" /> 
  </constructor-arg> 
  <constructor-arg> 
    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapStepExecutionDao"/> 
  </constructor-arg>
  <constructor-arg> 
     <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapExecutionContextDao"/> 
  </constructor-arg> 
</bean>
```

Comment: the job repository is created once, so it does not matter if your use prototype or not, can you explain a bit more how do you run the jobs?

Comment: you're probably going to need to create your own JobLauncher implementation (and others) to do this. @Michael Lange is correct in this case because you're creating  singleton simple job launcher that will create a 'single' job repo.  you need at least a job launcher per job if you're going to try to do this.

Comment: Why are you trying to do a repo per job?

Answer (score 1):

This one has worked for me, e.g. as a unit-test `jobRepository`:

```
<bean id="jobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
</bean>
```